# Get the most popular genre: Error 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT COUNT(Books.Genre), Borrower.bookid, Client.ClientDoB 
FROM Borrower
LEFT JOIN client ON client.clientid = borrower.clientid
LEFT JOIN books ON books.bookid = borrower.bookid
ORDER BY genre ASC
```

I'm trying to get the most popular genre that was purchased by clients with a certain DOB. Am I even supposed to be COUNTing here?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, so one can help providing the proper query for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you aggregate records, you need to group by non aggregated columns

so a group by is needed. Not sure if it gives you the desired result.. but here goes :

```
SELECT COUNT(Books.Genre),Borrower.bookid,Client.ClientDoB 
FROM Borrower
LEFT JOIN client
ON client.clientid = borrower.clientid
LEFT JOIN books
ON books.bookid = borrower.bookid

group by Borrower.bookid,Client.ClientDoB
```

Comment: If it answered your question, please mark it as the answer. Glad to be of help